# How to get Attribute value of calling method

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I would like to dynamically get the value of the attribute on method, which could be anywhere in the calling hierarchy.

Now I have found the solution using StackTrace's FrameCount and GetFrame. But it's not dynamic

Rollback.cs

```
namespace AnotationTest
{
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
 class RollbackAttribute: Attribute
 {
     public Guid RollbackGuid { get; set; }

     public RollbackAttribute()
     {
         RollbackGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
     }
 }
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Test();
     }

     [RollbackAttribute]
     public static void Test()
     {
         Test1();
     }

     public static void Test1()
     {
         Test2();
     }

     public static void Test2()
     {
         Test3();
     }
     public static void Test3()
     {
         Test4();
     }
     public static void Test4()
     {
         var framecount = new StackTrace().FrameCount;
         System.Reflection.MethodBase method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(framecount-2).GetMethod();
         RollbackAttribute rollback = (RollbackAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RollbackAttribute), true)[0];
     }
 }
```

I would like to have a solution to get the attribute value from the Test4 method. But without using StackTrace which is used now. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does "another child method" mean? Please add the "other child method" to the appropriate class in your source code in the question, and add a comment unambiguously identifying which method is the child. Name it `OtherChildMethod()`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem or even a 'bad design' problem to me.

Comment: I agree some info on why you need to do this would help so that  better solution can be found

Comment: I need to use something similar in my project, but I don't know exactly how to get the attribute value. I would like to not use the RollbackGuid as parametres for every Test methods.

Comment: also, a suitable solution for me would be to get full calling path - e.g. Test4 - Test 3 - Test 2 - Test 1 - Test - Main
is there anything faster than StackTrace

Comment: At some point, you had never given any thought to StackTrace. But then you had *a problem that you needed to solve*, a problem you haven't mentioned here. That's *Problem X*. We don't know what that problem was. You decided that the solution to that problem was to use StackTrace to get an attribute from method `Test4()`. Then you had a problem doing that, and that became *Problem Y*. You're asking us to solve *Problem Y*. If you tell us, in full detail, without ambiguity or mysteries, what *Problem X* is, we will solve *Problem Y* for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is CallContext and its Set/GetLogicalData methods that serves the purpose of traversing data from caller to "callee" without the need to use method parameters or attributes.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("rollbackGuid", Guid.NewGuid());
            Test();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            Test1();
        }

        //[RetryOnExceptionAttribute]
        public static void Test1()
        {
            Test2();
        }


        public static void Test2()
        {
            Test3();
        }


        public static void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current thread id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            Task.Run((() => { Test4(); }));
        }


        public static void Test4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current thread id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Rollback guid: {Rollback.CurrentGuid}");
        }
    }

    static class Rollback
    {
        public static Guid CurrentGuid => (Guid)CallContext.GetData("rollbackGuid");
    }
```